# Expats vs Expatriates?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

It may already be too late for this, but any thoughts on making it expats.SE rather than expatriates.SE?

I've lived in several countries now and been part of a few expat communities, and it's very rare to hear the full word 'expatriates'.

Plus, it's easier to type expats ;)

Comment: Note: pings sent, but stuff is a little crazy over in developer world, so it might be next week.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I thought of this when we brought the site up. The URL is expatriates, but expats *should* have been added as a redirect - I'll follow up on it and get it in place.

**Update:**

This is now done because Geoff Dalgas is awesome.

Comment: woo! Thanks Tim and Geoff!

Answer (score 2):

I think we should seriously consider making expats the canonical URL and expatriates the redirect.  I've never heard anyone use the full term "expatriate" in informal speech in either the East or the West.  People always, always say "expat," whether "expat contract," "I am an expat," or "Let's have dinner with those expats."

The full name is unwieldy, a waste of time to type, and people who have English as a second language may not even know how to spell it, even if they deal with "expats" from time to time.

By way of example, today this site was on the front page of Hacker News.  The title there was "The new Expats.Stackexchange Public Beta has launched."  It's good that there's a redirect, but it's not good that people refer to a domain which is not the official one--this dilutes the brand.

I'm curious to know what people think are the advantages of using "expatriates."

Comment: As a counterpoint, I have generally heard **only** the term "expatriate".

Comment: Oh, interesting, +1 for you sir.  My experience is from New York, London, and Singapore.  What about you?  Maybe it's regional?

Comment: Well I am originally from California (now in Germany), but I have mostly only ever heard it on television, or seen it in print. I don't really identify as an expatriate (although I am one), so that might play into it as well. I don't recall ever hearing it or using it conversationally, so that could be the difference as well.